# What sign conventions are used here? Geometrical optics

Tags: optics, conventions, geometric-optics

I'm reading *Theory and Problems in Optics* By Eugene Hecht (Schaum's outline series).

I'm not able to understand, What sort of sign convention are they using?

It says,

> Table 4-1 summarizes the sign convention we will adhere to - in all cases light is assumed to enter from the left. Notice that a negative value of $s_0$ or $s_i$ means a virtual object or a virtual image respectively.

[image: Table 4-1]

Note: Here $V$ stands for the vertex.

I don't understand one of the solved problems:

> Consider the block of glass show in fig. If the point source $S$ is $30$ cm from the vertex of the hemispherical end and if the latter has a radius of $10$ cm, locate the image seen by the observer.

[image: fig]

I think the sign of $s_o$ should be negative as it is measured opposite to light in the direction. But they have used the positive sign.

So Can someone make me understand the sign conversions used in the book?

Comment: The convention is that $S_i > 0$ when the image is on the opposite side of the lens that the object is on. 
And $S_o < 0$ when the image is on the same side of the lens as that of the object.

Comment: what about others like $f_o$?

Comment: So this summation uses always $s_0$ initially?

Comment: The references above give you values that are positive each specific case. The converse means that these values will be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention used by Hecht is:

1. For objects, their distance to the vertex is taken positive if they are at the left of the vertex.
2. For images, the other way around, their distance to V is positive if they are right of V.

Since light goes from left to right (another convention), real objects are at the left of V (light encounters them before going through the optical system), whereas real images are at the right (light rays actually cross after the system). The convention used in this book has the advantage that real objects have $s_o>0$ and real images have $s_i>0$.

> I think the sign of $s_o$ should be negative as it is measured opposite to light in the direction.

That could be a valid convention, measuring positive distances for objects and images always to the right of the vertex, but it's not the convention used in this book. If we were to use this convention, then real objects would have $s_o<0$ and real images $s_i>0$.

The fact is there is no canonical way of choosing these signs, it varies from book to book. The key is, once we stick to one convention, then all the formulae derived in geometrical optics will depend on this choice. As an example, the formula to calculate the position of the image when the optical system is just a single surface like OP's case; varies depending on the sign convention. It's given by

$$n\left(\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{s_o}\right)=n'\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{s_i}\right)$$

with Hecht's convention, and

$$n\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{s_o}\right)=n'\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{s_i}\right)$$

with OP's proposed convention. This last convention has the advantage, e.g, that one can define [Abbe's invariant](https://www.optowiki.info/glossary/abbe-invariant/)

$$Q=n\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{s_o}\right)=n'\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{s_i}\right).$$